# Find the most common word from user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap, windowbuilder

I'm very new to Java creating a software application that allows a user to input text into a field and the program runs through all of the text and identifies what the most common word is. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
JButton btnMostFrequentWord = new JButton("Most Frequent Word");
btnMostFrequentWord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String text = textArea.getText();
    String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
    HashMap<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : words) {
      int value = 0;
      if  (occurrences.containsKey(word)) {
        value = occurrences.get(word);
      }
      occurrences.put(word, value + 1);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most Frequent Word: " + occurrences.values());
  }
}
```

This just prints what the values of the words are, but I would like it to tell me what the number one most common word is instead. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after your `for` loop, you can sort the map by value then reverse the sorted entries by value and select the first.

```
for (String word: words) {
    int value = 0;
    if  (occurrences.containsKey(word)) {
        value = occurrences.get(word);
    }
    occurrences.put(word, value + 1);
}

Map.Entry<String,Integer> tempResult = occurrences.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .findFirst().get();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most Frequent Word: " + tempResult.getKey());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either iterate through occurrences map and find the max or 
Try like below

```
String text = textArea.getText();;
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
HashMap<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
int mostFreq = -1;
String mostFreqWord = null;

for (String word : words) {
    int value = 0;
    if (occurrences.containsKey(word)) {
        value = occurrences.get(word);
    }
    value = value + 1;
    occurrences.put(word, value);

    if (value > mostFreq) {
        mostFreq = value;
        mostFreqWord = word;
    }
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most Frequent Word: " + mostFreqWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
int max = 0;
String a = null;
for (String word : words) {
    int value = 0;
    if(occurrences.containsKey(word)){
        value = occurrences.get(word);
    }
    occurrences.put(word, value + 1);
    if(max < value+1){
        max = value+1;
        a = word;
    }
}
System.out.println(a);
```

You could sort it, and the solution would be much shorter, but I think this runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is more familiar with Java, here is a very easy way to do it with Java 8:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+"));

Collections.sort(words, Comparator.comparingInt(word -> {
    return Collections.frequency(words, word);
}).reversed());
```

The most common word is stored in `words.get(0)` after sorting.